# node.js: Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Why do I get this error?

`Node v8.9.1`

## code

```
var childProcess = require('child_process'),
    phantomjs = require('/var/bin/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt');

console.error = function(){
    require('system').stderr.write(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' ')+'\n');
    phantomjs.exit(1);
};

console.log('hey', phantomjs.path)
console.error('error')

childProcess.execFile(phantomjs.path, require('system').args, function(err, stdout, stderr){
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    }

    if(stderr){
        console.error(stderr);
    }

    console.log(stdout);
});
```

## error

```
# /var/bin/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs phantom.js
Error: Cannot find module 'path'

  phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:299 in require
  phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:263 in require
  phantomjs://platform/phantomjs.js:10
hey undefined
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'phantomjs.exit(1)')

  phantomjs://code/phantom.js:6 in error
error
```

Comment: You might want to be sure `system` is built in as I just checked the Node docs and didn't find `system` listed.
What version of Node are you running?

Comment: `Node v8.9.1` .

Comment: yhaa I also don't think system is a core module, you can run the code at http://rextester.com/l/nodejs_online_compiler with one simple require for conformation.

Comment: Now please post your `phantom.js` file contents

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system` is not a Node built-in module, [it's part of PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/system/). It won't be available if you're just running your script with the standard `node` command. [As shown in the documentation](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html), you need to use the `phantomjs` command, like so:

```
phantomjs phantom.js
```

Comment: Have updated my question.. Now I just get a new error